# Bar chart label alignment for all the zero values

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, bar-chart

I am using high-chart library for bar chart. Everything is working fine except one thing. 
When all the values in bar are 'ZERO', the alignment has changed into right side. I want to make it left align. For any non zero values it's working as expected.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvp1ebsj/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        },

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify',
            align:'left'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }]
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If all values are 0, then `max` can not be calculated, so Highcharts will render values in the middle. You can force labels to be rendered on the left by setting `yAxis.max` or `yAxis.softMax`, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mvp1ebsj/1/

Comment: It's working fine. thnx

Comment: Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values are `0`, then `max` can not be calculated, so Highcharts will render values in the middle. You can force labels to be rendered on the left by setting `yAxis.max` or `yAxis.softMax`, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mvp1ebsj/1/